# How to break line with sweet alert

Tags: angular, typescript, sweetalert2

I want break line some text at swal.text of sweet alert 2. I tried br, \r \n , join(\n\n) but not working for me! Please help me to resolve my problem. Tks for your help :D. this is my code

```
<swal #extractDataDoneSwal
      title="Exported"
      text="Your files have been exported"
      icon="success">
</swal>

if (data == "1") {
  this.exportFile = this.insurerNo.toString() + "_Med.SAT";
  this.loading = false;
  const lines = ['Your files have been exported',this.exportFile];
  this.extractDataDoneSwal.text = lines.join('\n\n');
  this.extractDataDoneSwal.fire();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try using the property 'html' instead of 'text'. Referring to the documentation:

> html property: A HTML description for the modal. It can either be added to the object under the key "html" or passed as the second parameter of the function.

> text property: A description for the modal. If "text" and "html" parameters are provided in the same time, "text" will be used.

That way you can add any HTML markup and thus achieve such result. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Tks for your help. This solution has been resolved my problems. Tks